# Spark: Solrj exception on serialization

Tags: scala, apache-spark, solr, solrj

I am trying to import some csv file to Solr using Spark as "pipe", in this way:

```
trait SparkConnector {

  def connectionWrapper[A](f: SparkContext => A): A = {
    val sc: SparkContext = getSparkContext()
    val res: A = f(sc)
    sc.stop
    res
  }
}

object SolrIndexBuilder extends SparkConnector {

  val solr = new ConcurrentUpdateSolrClient ("http://some-solr-url", 10000, 5)

  def run(implicit fileSystem: FileSystem) = connectionWrapper[Unit] {
    sparkContext =>

      def build(): Unit = {

        def toSolrDocument(person: Map[String, String], fieldNames: Array[String]): SolrInputDocument = {
          val doc = new SolrInputDocument()
          //add the values to the solr doc
          doc
        }

    def rddToMapWithHeaderUnchecked(rdd: RDD[String], header: Array[String]): RDD[Map[String, String]] =
        rdd.map { line =>
          val splits = new CSVParser().parseLine(line)
          header.zip(splits).toMap
        }

    val indexCsv = sparkContext.textFile("/somewhere/filename.csv")
        val fieldNames = Vector("field1", "field2", "field3", ...)

        val indexRows = rddToMapWithHeaderUnchecked(indexCsv, fieldNames)
        indexRows.map(row => toSolrDocument(row, fieldNames)).foreach { doc => solr.add(doc) }

        if (!indexRows.isEmpty()) {
          solr.blockUntilFinished()
          solr.commit()
        }
      }

      build()
  }
}
```

Running the code on a cluster (Spark-mode) I get the following error:

```
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.http.impl.client.SystemDefaultHttpClient
Serialization stack:
    - object not serializable (class: org.apache.http.impl.client.SystemDefaultHttpClient, value: org.apache.http.impl.client.SystemDefaultHttpClient@3bdd79c7)
    - field (class: org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient, name: httpClient, type: interface org.apache.http.client.HttpClient)
    - object (class org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient, org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient@5d2c576a)
    - field (class: org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.ConcurrentUpdateSolrClient, name: client, type: class org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient)
    - object (class org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.ConcurrentUpdateSolrClient, org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.ConcurrentUpdateSolrClient@5da7593d)
    - field (class: com.oneninetwo.andromeda.solr.SolrIndexBuilder$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$build$1$2, name: solr$1, type: class org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.ConcurrentUpdateSolrClient)
    - object (class com.oneninetwo.andromeda.solr.SolrIndexBuilder$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$build$1$2, <function1>)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$.improveException(SerializationDebugger.scala:40)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:301)
    ... 26 more
```

which clearly states that I cannot serialize classes related to Solrj (and relative dependencies).

I tried different thing but I am cannot find a way to make it work. Any help?

**UPDATE**

This is one solution I have found:

```
indexRows.map(row => toSolrDocument(row, fieldNames)).foreachPartition{ partition =>
          val solr = new ConcurrentUpdateSolrClient(...)
          partition.foreach { doc  =>
            solr.add(doc)
          }
          solr.commit()
```

Comment: This is not a solution to your question, but rather an alternative: if you have a look in the [twitter spark-solr example](https://github.com/lucidworks/spark-solr/blob/master/src/main/java/com/lucidworks/spark/example/streaming/TwitterToSolrStreamProcessor.java) you'll see that the solr adding is done on the master (see [SolrSupport.scala](https://github.com/lucidworks/spark-solr/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/lucidworks/spark/util/SolrSupport.scala) and  not on the slaves).

Comment: you mean that the instance of "solr client" is built outside the "foreachPartition"? In that case I tried to do it, but it didn't work for me.

Comment: A bit more explanation would be nice, having the same issue